# How to integrate Mysql data using PHP in this ParamQuery Grid Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How can I change the JSON format of mysql output to something like the below mentioned expected format.kindly help to convert the JSON output to expected output.

## JSON

```
[
    {"storenm": "S1", "FA_SOH": "20964", "FA_CY_QTY": "15", "FA_CT_QTY": "44497"},
    {"storenm": "S2", "FA_SOH": "1096", "FA_CY_QTY": "2", "FA_CT_QTY": "7501"}
];
```

## Expected

```
[
    [S1, '20964', '15', '44497'],
    [S2, '1096', '2', '7501']
];
```

This is my updated PHP file for your reference:

## PHP

```
<?PHP

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sth = mysqli_query($con,"select storenm,FA_SOH,FA_CY_QTY,FA_CT_QTY from pr_report");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {

        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $json_data=json_encode($rows);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
    <script src="pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/office/pqgrid.css" />

<script>
    $(function () {
    var data = <?PHP echo $json_data;?>;
    /*var data = [[1, 'Exxon Mobil', '339,938.0', '36,130.0'],
        [2, 'Wal-Mart Stores', '315,654.0', '11,231.0'],
        [3, 'Royal Dutch Shell', '306,731.0', '25,311.0'],
        [4, 'BP', '267,600.0', '22,341.0'],
        [5, 'General Motors', '192,604.0', '-10,567.0'],
        [6, 'Chevron', '189,481.0', '14,099.0'],
        [7, 'DaimlerChrysler', '186,106.3', '3,536.3'],
        [8, 'Toyota Motor', '185,805.0', '12,119.6'],
        [9, 'Ford Motor', '177,210.0', '2,024.0'],
        [10, 'ConocoPhillips', '166,683.0', '13,529.0'],
        [11, 'General Electric', '157,153.0', '16,353.0'],
        [12, 'Total', '152,360.7', '15,250.0'],
        [13, 'ING Group', '138,235.3', '8,958.9'],
        [14, 'Citigroup', '131,045.0', '24,589.0'],
        [15, 'AXA', '129,839.2', '5,186.5'],
        [16, 'Allianz', '121,406.0', '5,442.4'],
        [17, 'Volkswagen', '118,376.6', '1,391.7'],
        [18, 'Fortis', '112,351.4', '4,896.3'],
        [19, 'Crédit Agricole', '110,764.6', '7,434.3'],
        [20, 'American Intl. Group', '108,905.0', '10,477.0']];
        */

        var obj = { 
        freezeRows: 0,
            freezeCols: 1,
            editable: false,  
            resizable: true,
        width: 700, 
        height: 400, 
        title: "ParamQuery Grid Example",
        resizable:true,
        draggable:true };

        obj.colModel = [{ 
        title: "Rank", width: 100, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "Company", width: 200, dataType: "float" },
        { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float",align: "right" },
        { title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float", align: "right"}];

        obj.dataModel = { data: data };
        $("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);
    });
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid_array" style="margin:100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)` to `mysqli_fetch_array($sth, MYSQLI_NUM)`